# Matplotlib raw latex "\epsilon" only yields "\varepsilon"

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, macports

I'm using Matplotlib to analyze results & generate figures. I need Greek symbols in the legend and axis labels, including $\epsilon$. However, the resulting text doesn't distinguish between "normal" \epsilon and \varepsilon --- both of them appear as \varepsilon. Here's a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0 + 0.01, 0.01)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(t, s, 'k-', linewidth=2.0, label=r'$\epsilon$, $\varepsilon$, $\phi$, $\varphi$, $\sigma$, $\varsigma$')
plt.title(r'$\epsilon$, $\varepsilon$, $\phi$, $\varphi$, $\sigma$, $\varsigma$')
plt.xlabel(r'$t [M]$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\epsilon$, $\varepsilon$, $\phi$, $\varphi$, $\sigma$, $\varsigma$')
ax.legend(ncol=2, loc='lower left', fancybox=True)
plt.show()
```

When I process this on my Macbook (OS X El Capitan with Macports installations of TexLive and py27-matplotlib), everything renders correctly *except* the \epsilon.

ETA: the code does the right thing on a different machine (Scientific Linux).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not using TeX in your script. Matplotlib provides what is called [MathText](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html), which is a subset of LaTeX commands, rendered in normal UTF8 characters. This is how MathText looks like with the default fontset:

[image]

You can change the fontset to have "\varepsilon" look different than "\epsilon". However, it seems that out of the available fontsets, only "cm" has actually different symbols for those commands.

```
plt.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "cm"
```

This will produce:

[image]

---

In order to have Latex used to render your text, you need to specifically tell matplotlib to do so. One option is to use

```
plt.rcParams["text.usetex"] =True
```

at the beginning of your script. This requires a working TeX installation.
The example would then look like this, where "\varepsilon" and "\epsilon" are indeed different.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I always have a working LaTeX installation, so it didn't occur to me that it wasn't being accessed here. It's weird that MathText has this little quirk for \epsilon, when it works fine for the other Greek letters with variant forms.

Comment: You are correct, there is also the option to use \varepsilon in MathText. You would need to select a different fontset. I updated the answer.

Comment: BTW, the MathText page you linked to still *claims* that \epsilon is available (distinct from \varepsilon). Thus the failure seems to be in how MathText is trying to implement it, and the font family it uses on my Macbook fails.

I found this on the matplotlob users list archive, where someone suggests switching font.sans in the user's matplotlibrc file (doesn't work for me):

http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/default-mathtext-font-td16421.html

ETA: you addressed this in your edited comment. I might try "cm" instead of the DejaVu Sans suggested in the archived discussion I found.

Comment: So you mean `["mathtext.fontset"] = "cm"` does not work on mac? That's a pitty. In this case you probably need to use true Latex.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.

What didn't work was my attempt to use "Deja Vu Sans", which was the suggestion I found on the old mailing list discussion.

However, "cm" *does* work, and is certainly quicker than waiting for the whole TeX compilation.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer correctly explains how the interpretation of the `\varepsilon` and `\epsilon` depends on the matplotlib mathtext fontset.

The ‘bigger picture’ reason has to do with the fact that the most common form of the epsilon is **ε**, but Knuth for some reason decided to use **ϵ** as `\epsilon` in TeX. This creates some confusion. In actual Greek text, they're simply stylistic variants, while as mathematical symbols, they can have different meanings. Therefore, Unicode includes both symbols. In the Greek section, `U+3B5` *GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON* is **ε**, and `U+03F5` *GREEK LUNATE EPSILON SYMBOL* is **ϵ**. Variants of both can also be found in the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols section of Unicode.

If you use the Unicode characters in your Python source code rather than the TeX-style mnemonics, you will get the correct symbol.

```py
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0 + 0.01, 0.01)
s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(t, s, 'k-', linewidth=2.0, label='$ϵ$, $ε$, $ϕ$, $φ$, $σ$, $ς$')
plt.title('$ϵ$, $ε$, $ϕ$, $φ$, $σ$, $ς$')
plt.xlabel(r'$t [M]$')
plt.ylabel('$ϵ$, $ε$, $ϕ$, $φ$, $σ$, $ς$')
ax.legend(ncol=2, loc='lower left', fancybox=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('greek.png')
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Report from 2023: it works well!

Answer (score 2):

By default matplotlib uses some rather basic engine to parse your labels (not sure what it is exactly). You can switch to the "normal" tex engine by adding `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)` before plotting/rendering. Your script will execute a little slower, but you gain full access to latex features.

edit: By default [mathtext](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial) is used.